# How to unset an arg in tcl

Tags: tcl, expect

I am taking arguments from command line and passing all those arguments to another program (with expect spawn). I want to parse all options and omit some of them (or do something else). To do that I am doing this:

```
set arguments [lrange $argv 0 end]

#Check for -lp option. Set the program path 
for {set var 0} {$var<$argc} {incr var} {
    if {[lindex $arguments $var] == "-lp" || [lindex $arguments $var] == "--launcher-path"} {
        if {[lindex $arguments [expr {$var+1}]] != ""} {
            set program [lindex $arguments [expr {$var+1}]]
            #unset [lindex $arguments $var]
        } else {
            puts "E: Argument missing for option: [lindex $arguments $var]"
            exit 1
        }
    }
}
```

But I can't figure out how to unset those args that I used. For example, I need to unset `[lindex $arguments [expr {$var+1}]]` and `[lindex $arguments $var]`.

This is how I am running the `$program`:

```
if {[catch {spawn $program --text {*}$arguments}]} {
    puts "E: Launcher not found: $program"
    exit 1
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I have done it:

```
set arguments [lreplace $arguments [expr {$var+1}] [expr {$var+1}]]
set arguments [lreplace $arguments $var $var]
```

As [glenn-jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman) pointed out, the above can be shortened to:

```
set arguments [lreplace $arguments $var [expr {$var+1}]]
```

Comment: You might as well do that in one command: `set arguments [lreplace $arguments $var [expr {$var+1}]]`

Comment: @glennjackman , cool, didn't catch that. Just learning the basics of tcl... May I edit my answer and include that?

Comment: yes of course. Everything on this site is [creative commons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing), so share away.

Answer (score 1):

If your arguments are all key-value, then you can iterate over the arguments in pairs with `foreach` and build up a new list containing just the arguments you're interested in.

```
set newarguments [list]
foreach {arg value} $arguments {
    switch -exact -- $arg {
        "-lp" -
        "--launcher-path" {
            set program $value
        }
        default {
            lappend newarguments $arg $value
        }
    }
}
```

If you have mixed flag and key-value options, then you will need to iterate using an index, similar to your code, but building up the new list of arguments will be roughly the same.

You could also check into the tcllib [`cmdline` package](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/cmdline/cmdline.html), although that does not handle long options.